# Why does the second light go out when the first bulb is removed?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have recently added another light fixture to a switch that used to just control 1 entry light. Now that switch controls both of them & have found out that they are both dependent on having working bulbs in them to both work. If one is removed, or burned out, both will not work. My problem is I have 1 light that is working and the second light is either extremely dim or not even lit up at all. What can I do?

Comment: This sounds like you have fixtures wired in series rather than parallel. Not standard in any locale that I know of. Where are you located and what sort of power system do you have?

Comment: Yes.  Definitely sounds like a series installation.

Comment: You almost certainly have them installed in [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_and_parallel_circuits) rather than parallel - so they are wired incorrectly.  Another indication is that, when on, the bulbs are dim if they're incandescent, or don't work at all if they're florescent.  This is because both bulbs are only receiving half the voltage they're supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rewire. The light fixture that you tapped into should be redone so that the three wires (power in, light fixture, power out) are all connected to each other.